# Configure existing VNET while creating Microsoft Azure Container Service (DC/OS)

Tags: azure, acs, azure-container-service

We have our own VNET configured. I would like to use the same VNET / subnet while creating the ACS service. I am using DC/OS.
Can I configure the VNET / Subnet and NSG through Azure ACS template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time configuring VNets is not possible. However this is something we will be fixing very soon. First through some open source template, and once fully tested, through the ACS resource provider in ARM.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any tentative timelines for releasing the same? Q1-2017 or later?

Comment: It seems that my edit is not being moderated through, so here's the update in a comment...

ACE Engine, the open source code behind ACS, supports this feature now (http://github.com/acs-engine), this will become a part of the official ACS service at some point in the not too distant future.